# Facebook Android API- How to know when friend list of a user has updated?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, android-sqlite

Currently i am working on facebook based android application and i store all friends of user to a sqlite database on login. I want to update this database only when user adds or removes a friend. How to know friend list updated not?? any FQL or Graph api calls regarding this??
Note: checking friend count is not a good solution because if user adds a new friend and removes an existing one then we go wrong!
Another solution is comparing our database friends with the friend list from facebook server, but its long process if user have large number of friends.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879123/get-fql-real-time-updates